# How does && operator work with Point geometry as a parameter

Tags: postgis, postgresql

I am new to PostGIS. I am trying to understand `&&` operator. Documentation says

> boolean &&( geometry A , geometry B );

> The && operator returns TRUE if the 2D bounding box of geometry A intersects the 2D bounding box of geometry B.

If first parameter is `Point` geometry and second is `Polygon` geometry, how does `Point` form a 2D bounding box to know if it intersects with `Polygon`? My understand is `Point` alone can't have a bounding box, is that correct?

Comment: No, that's incorrect. The envelope of a point is the point itself (min=max).

Answer (score 1):

The bounding box of a point has size zero, but still valid coordinates:

```
SELECT Box2D(ST_MakePoint(12, 34));

      box2d
------------------
 BOX(12 34,12 34)
```